# Why won't my function print

Tags: python, printing

So I have this function.

```
def test(fourBits):
  binaryDigits = fourBits
  if binaryDigits[1] == 1:
     print 'test'
```

If I enter `test('1111')` it won't print `test`. I don't understand why it is not?

Comment: because '1111' is a string whereas 1 is an integer.

Comment: No need to set a local variable in the method too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
if int(binaryDigits[1]) == 1:
```

or this:

```
if binaryDigits[1] == '1':
```

so that the types match, i.e., compare two characters or two numbers.

Answer (score 3):

binaryDigits[1] is a string, 1 is an integer

Comment: Cheers guys I knew it was something dumb. Live and learn I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you want is something like this.  Use integer instead of string, and test the bit by bitwise operators.

```
def test(value):
    if (value >> 1) & 1:
        print 'true'
```

Here is the result.

```
>>> test(0b0010)
true
>>> test(0b0000)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `print binaryDigits[1]` before your `if` statement to see what is being hidden by your `if` statement.

Comment: Not useful here. `'1'` and `1` print the exact same thing.

Comment: `print repr(...)` is more helpful in this case